# Elastic Stack - REST API logging with full JSON request and response

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

### Background

We have a web server written in Java that communicates with thousands of mobile apps via HTTPS REST APIs.

For investigation purposes we have to log all API calls - currently this is implemented as a programming `@Aspect`, and for each API call we save an `api_call_log` object into a MySQL table with the following attributes:

- `tenant_id`
- `username`
- `device_uuid`
- `api_method`
- `api_version`
- `api_start_time`
- `api_processing_duration`
- `request_parameters`
- `full_request` (JSON)
- `full_response` (JSON)
- `response_code`

### Problem

As you can imagine after reaching a certain throughput this solution doesn't scale well, and also querying this table is very slow even with the use of the right MySQL indices.

### Approach

That's why we want to use the **Elastic Stack** to re-implement this solution, however I am a bit stuck at the moment.

### Question

I couldn't found any Logstash plugins yet that would suit my needs - should I output this `api_call_log` object into a log file instead and use Logstash to parse, filter and transform that file?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly this is what I would do in this case. Write your log to a file using a framework like logback, rotate it. If you want  easy parsing use json as logging format (also available in logback). Then use Filebeat in order to ingest the logfile as it gets written. If you need to transform/parse the messages in elasticsearch ingest nodes using pipelines.

Consider tagging/enriching the logfiles read by filebeat with machine or enviroment specific informations in order to ask for them in your visualisation or report etc.

The filebeat-to-elastic approach is the simplest one. Try this first. If you can't get your parsing done in elasticsearch pipelines, put a logstash in between.

Using filebeat you'll get many stuff for free like backpressure handling and daily indicies what comes very handy in the logging scenario we are discussing here.

When you need a visualization or search ui, have a look on kibana or grafana.

And if you have more questions, raise a new question here.

Have Fun!

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ibexit. Is there any need for me to use Beats / Packetbeat for this? Would this solution better implemented if I would write a custom Beat?